# Timing this programs duration while it runs

Tags: python, while-loop

Here's the entire program, but I'm trying to figure out how to time it (days:hours:minutes:seconds) if at all possible. It is written in Python.

```
import random

x = 1
attempt = 0
while x ==1:
  rand1 = random.randint(1,1000)
  rand2 = random.randint(1,1000)
  attempt = attempt + 1
  if rand1 ==rand2:
    x=2
    print(rand1)
    print(rand2)
    print("Match Found.")
  else:
    print(rand1)
    print(rand2)
    print("Trying again.")
print("")
print("It took ", attempt," attempts to find a matching number.")
#for x in range(10):
# rand1 = random.randint(1,101)
# print(rand1)
# ignore the googol that's what I'm using when I figure out how to time it -> 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

The better code:

```
import random
import time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
print('Current time: %s' % datetime. now())


attempt = 0
start_time = time.time()
while 1:
  rand1 = random.randint(1,1000)
  rand2 = random.randint(1,1000)
  attempt += 1
  if rand1 == rand2:
    print(rand1)
    print(rand2)
    print("Match Found.", end = '\n\n')
    break
  else:
    print(rand1)
    print(rand2)
    print("Trying again.", end = '\n\n')
print("It took %s attempts to find a matching number." % attempt)
print("It took %s to finish" % str(timedelta(seconds=(time.time() - start_time))))
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make it have more than just seconds displayed? I'm trying to time something that could possibly run up to days (if you tested the program, I'm trying to make it do that same, but for a match between one and a googol). If not, that's alright, It'll be time for h*lla division lol.

Comment: Edited! It's that ok? I have created a function to convert seconds to possibly run up to days

Comment: Says that there's an error in lines 8 and 27, and that reduce is not defined.

Comment: Sorry, the old code is for python2. Fixed! Can you check it?

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! This was extremely helpful, thank you for putting up with me making you reedit your additions/changes.

Comment: You are welcome!!! Can you give a tick for this answer to everyone can know that the question has been solved